# Is it required to pass the super class parameter for the subclass it is inheriting from?

Tags: java, c#, inheritance, super, radix

So I haven been learning Java for a while but decided to switch to C#. It's been a while so I may forget some things. What I know is that in Java, when inheriting from a super class you can or can not call the super class and pass in the parameter if it accepts it.
For example:

```
public class Super
{
    public Super(int x)
    {
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super
{
    public Sub()
    {
        super(5);
    }
}
```

and then this other example:

```
public class Super
{
    public Super(int x)
    {
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super
{
    public Sub()
    {

    }
}
```

is also totally fine since it does not have to pass in parameter to the superclass, correct me if I am wrong. But then in C#, I am not sure if you are required to pass in the parameter for the superclass or not(like if it is still legal and won't cause any problem)

Comment: you can pass parameter like:
class (param) : base(param)

Comment: `But then in C#, I am not sure if you are required to pass in the parameter for the superclass or not` **"Try it and see"** would be my recommendation. https://dotnetfiddle.net/kK7TfK

Comment: Yes, you are wrong about Java. Your second code snippet does not compile as you are required to pass the parameter to the superclass constructor.